# Mule ESB receive over HTTPS

Tags: java, esb, mule

Last mule question for now:

```
<https:connector name="httpsConnector" doc:name="HTTP\HTTPS">
<https:tls-key-store path="keystore.jks" keyPassword="pass" storePassword="pass"/>
</https:connector>


<https:inbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response" host="localhost" port="65081" path="path" connector-ref="httpsConnector" doc:name="HTTP"/>
```

So I have those two snippets in my code, yet whenever it starts i get:

```
1. The required object/property "tls-key-store" is null (org.mule.transport.ConnectException)
```

But the tls-key-store isn't null.

Whats going on?

Thanks

Tom

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is usually caused when the keystore.jks can't locate the within your application. Can you make sure that it is present in the classpath or set the whole path as the value of the path attribute

Comment: Thanks, I'll have a look, I was following the wiki page, it says if its in the resources directory then it doesn't require a path. I'll add a full path and see what happens.

Comment: Please don't :) I think that the problem was only that the keystore wasn't copied properly in the classpath during the project build.